# Surface Interface Conditions for Electric and Magnetic Fields

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electric-fields, boundary-conditions

My question concerns the expressions for field discontinuities across a surface density for electric and magnetic fields. I know that both of them are given, respectively, by

$\vec{E}_{dis} = \frac{\sigma}{\epsilon_0}\hat{n}$

and

$\vec{B}_{dis} = \mu_0\mathcal{J}\hat{t}$

where $\hat{n}$ and $\hat{t}$ are normal and tangential unit vectors for the surface and $\sigma$ and $\mathcal{J}$ are the surface charge and surface current densities, respectively. However, I have not seen a proof that I felt was fully rigorous. All of the proofs that I have seen make use of thin Gaussian pillboxes, or infinitesimal rectangles in the case of the magnetic field discontinuity. I don't know if using these objects is entirely justified without first explicitly constructing them and then taking the limit as their relevant dimensions approach zero. Could anyone perhaps provide such proofs for these two expressions? A proof that relies on deriving the results from Poisson's equation will be even better if it can be done.

Comment: This is a tall order -- It's like asking for a definition of a delta function that wouldn't make a mathematician fwow ub.

Comment: So would this question have a better home in the mathematics stack exchange, then?